# Angularjs route resolve that successfully returns data produces undefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have some data loaded into my controller when the appropriate route is triggered.  However even though my call to the server successfully retrieves data the `logDatas` value always returns undefined.  Every example I have come across seems to indicate that I am in fact using the resolve value on the routeProvider correctly.  So I am really at a loss at this point.

Is it simply not possible to use a deferred in the way that I am?

```
//controller definition

.controller('ListController',  ['$scope','$location','$q','$rootScope','$http',function($scope,$location,$q,$rootScope,$http,logDatas){

$q.all([logDatas]).then(function(result){ //This returns undefined.
console.log(result);
$scope.logData=result;

});


$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 10;

$scope.numPages = function () {
return Math.ceil($scope.numPerPage / $scope.logData.length );
};

$scope.reload=function(){
    var deffered=$q.defer();
    var success=function(result){
        if(angular.equals(result,[])){
            deffered.reject("No Events found.");
        }else{
            deffered.resolve(result);
        }
    };
    $scope.logData= $http.post('api/call',success);
    return deffered.promise;    
};
$scope.reset=function(data){
$scope.offset=0;
    $scope.logData=data;
//  $scope.reload();

};

$rootScope.$on('update-data',function(e, data){
    $scope.logData=data;
});
}])

//route
.when('/list',{controller:'ListController',templateUrl:'Content/app/partials/list.html',     resolve:{
        logDatas:function(Resolvers){return Resolvers.Events.data;}}

})

//Service
services.factory('Resolvers',['$http','$q','Event',function($http,$q,Event){
return{Events:{data:function(){
var deferred=$q.defer();
var success=function(result){
        if(angular.equals(result,[])){
            deffered.reject("No Events found.");
        }else{
            deffered.resolve(result);
        }
    };

    $http.post('api/call');
return deferred.promise;

    }}};
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that there is a typo in the original post.  The underlying problem was that I had the controller set in the view.  Removing ng-controller caused things to work as expected.

Given:

```
.when('/list',{controller:'ListController',templateUrl:'Content/app/partials/list.html',
resolve:{
    logDatas:function(Resolvers){return Resolvers.Events.data;}}

})
```

Don't have:

```
<some-element ng-controller="ListController"></some-element>
```

in the view that templateUrl is set to.

Answer (score 2):

```
.controller('ListController',  ['$scope','$location','$q','$rootScope','$http',function($scope,$location,$q,$rootScope,$http,logDatas){
```

should be:

```
.controller('ListController',  ['$scope','$location','$q','$rootScope','$http','logDatas',function($scope,$location,$q,$rootScope,$http,logDatas){
```

Comment: That would appear to make the question of the class "typographical error"?

Comment: There indeed was a type in my original posting but that wasn't really what the problem was.  I would upvote you if I could though.